# System process holding WCF TCP port after application using it is closed

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf

I'm developing a C# .NET Framework based Web Service Library which is running over port 8733. Now I want to quickly create a console application that can start an instance of ServiceHost and host the Service so I don't need to have VS open and debugging it to have the Web Service running.

Here is my dirty console application code:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WebService));
    var bindig = new BasicHttpsBinding();
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWebService), binding, new Uri("https://192.168.0.154:8733"));

    host.Open();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But this throws an Exception when it hits `host.Open()`

> System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: 'HTTP could not register URL https://+:8733/. Another application has already registered this URL with HTTP.SYS.'
>
> Inner Exception
>   HttpListenerException: Failed to listen on prefix 'https://+:8733/' because it conflicts with an existing registration on the machine.

So I thought "Oh I just forgot to stop the instance running from Visual Studio", but nope, that was stopped.
So I decided to investigate using `netstat` in a PowerShell window ran as Administrator. Executing `netstat -a -o -n -b` and piping it into a `findstr "8733"` I get the result

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8733           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:8733              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
```

Now using Task Manager I go and search for the process with the PID 4, lo and behold: [image: System]

Now I have no idea why the System process is holding on to TCP Port 8733, and this even persists after a reboot. My question now is this; How can I manually bind to this Port?

P.S: Bonus points for answers that answer why the System process is holding the port and how the Web Service can bind to it when run from Visual Studio

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you don't also have an actual service version of your app installed/running? (it is normal for the System process to be the one having https ports open.)

Comment: Your code doesn't stop the service itself. Add a `host.Close()` at the end the way [the class's documemtation example shows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.servicehost?view=netframework-4.8) or wrap the object in a `using` block

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Damn, thanks for the question. I just checked again, Visual Studio wasn't running it anymore but IIS still had it registered...  
Still very confused on how Visual Studio could still host it though...

Comment: I think it's to do with the listening you get in the background as ServiceHost registers on your performance counters. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/ServiceHost.cs,dc1bd80b5a6c4be7 and you're not disposing it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am very aware that I need to close the host when I'm using it, but as of right now my problem is with starting it (which hasn't worked until now). Also my Console Application exits after that Console.ReadLine so the Address gets freed up anyways

Comment: The port number is probably in a service that automatically get started.  Can you sue a different port number?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an administrator account to run the service or use the below command to reserve the URL for the specific user so that it could occupy the system port arbitrarily.

> Netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:8001/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user

Official document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/add-urlacl
The system continues to occupy a port, possibly because our website in IIS is bound to some port.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.